# Store Pointers to Multiple Functions in Array

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I have some sample code that creates an array of pointers and stores the pointers to multiple functions in it (in this case, callback functions for an interrupt). This sample code builds in one compiler (gcc), and not in another(IAR). Just curious why it wouldn't work in one compiler. Is it potentially bad practice?

```
typedef void (*tc_channel_ptr)(uint32_t);
tc_channel_ptr tc0_channel_cb[TC_CHANNEL_COUNT];

void tc_register_callback(void *hw, uint8_t channel, void *cb)
{
    tc0_channel_cb[channel] = cb;
}
```

IAR gives an error: "a value of type "void*" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "tc_channel_ptr"

Comment: Add a type cast: `tc0_channel_cb[channel] = (tc_channel_ptr)cb;`

Comment: Why don't you just declare `cb` with the correct type?

Comment: IAR is broken/non-standard. Your code is valid for std C. As Barmar suggested, just do: `tc_channel_ptr cb` This solves the issue and adds extra type safety to the call of your function.

Comment: @CraigEstey No, IAR is entirely correct here (and GCC also complains about this code when compiling with `-pedantic-errors`). There’s no implicit conversion between function pointers and `void*`, and it isn’t even defined whether such a conversion must work.

Answer (score 2):

> IAR gives an error: "a value of type "void*" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "tc_channel_ptr"

IAR is justified in doing so. C permits `void *` to be converted to any other *object* pointer type, and such conversions are performed automatically by the assignment operator, but C does not make any provision for `void *` to be converted to *function* pointer types.  The behavior of your assignment is therefore undefined.

GCC exercises an extension in accepting your code.  It is within its rights to do so, but it is not valid to infer from its acceptance that the code is strictly conforming or that other compilers must accept it.

Bottom line: your callback registration function should specify the correct type for its third argument:

```
void tc_register_callback(void *hw, uint8_t channel, tc_channel_ptr cb)
{
    tc0_channel_cb[channel] = cb;
}
```

I don't see any advantage to declaring `cb` as a `void *` instead.

---

As a separate matter, I strongly agree with [your other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70701218/2402272) that you should not hide pointer nature behind a typedef.  That is a matter of style, however, not code correctness.  It is not related to the error you observe.

Comment: Yes, @KonradRudolph, I'm sure.  This falls into the category of code for which the specification does not define any behavior.  By definition, then, its behavior is exactly as undefined as if the specification explicitly said it was undefined.  Additionally, it violates a language constraint (C17 6.5.16.1/1), so not only is the behavior undefined, but a conforming compiler is obligated to emit a diagnostic.

Comment: IAR is used in embedded development and people who program uCs usually do not care too much about code portability. But C is right and pointer and function pointer can be completely different. I recently was programming custom uC where program address space was 32 bits but data only 16. So the `void *` pointer would not convert correctly to the function pointer and vice versa

Answer (score 1):

I would not hide pointers (even the function pointers) behind the `typedef`s. If you do not, it is very easy to see if something is pointer or not.

```
typedef void tc_channel_func(uint32_t);
tc_channel_func *tc0_channel_cb[TC_CHANNEL_COUNT];

void tc_register_callback(void *hw, uint8_t channel, void *cb)
{
    tc0_channel_cb[channel] = (tc_channel_func *)cb;
}
```

or

```
void tc_register_callback(void *hw, uint8_t channel, tc_channel_func *cb)
{
    tc0_channel_cb[channel] = cb;
}
```

but the second version can move the problem to another part of the code.